# Trying to add secrets to GoCD pipeline in code, with docker

Tags: typescript, docker, pipeline, go-cd

I am hoping that someone can fill in a knowledge gap for me.  In my typescript application I have created a pipeline in my code for my build and this is working.  However, in my package.json I currently have my username and password hard-coded.  I am assuming that I add the username and password to the environment as secure variables?  If so, how do I reference them in typescript?  I found examples for other environments but not typescript.

```
"sendToSharePoint": "m365 login --authType password --userName myUserName --password myPassword"
```

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be that I am building this through docker and I need to pass through the environment var.  Trying to figure out how to do that.

exec:
command: bash
arguments:
- -c
- docker run prt-ofg-spet -env USERNAME=$USERNAME npm run-script wholeProcess

Answer (score 1):

**in pipeline file:**

- docker run -e DEPLOY_USER=${DEPLOY_USER} -e DEPLOY_USER_PASSWORD=${DEPLOY_USER_PASSWORD}

**in package.json script**

"sendToSharePoint": "m365 login --authType password --userName $DEPLOY_USER --password $DEPLOY_USER_PASSWORD "

Still struggling to use secure secrets